# Who pays for replacement korban?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, korban, kavana-intent

When the kohen does an avodah shelo l'shma and the baal must bring another, who pays for the second animal?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99162/170

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of היזק שאינו ניכר unnoticeable damages. According to Torah law one is exempt from payment in such cases, but the Sages instituted that one who damages someone else's property in this way on purpose must pay. If it was an accident though then the damager remains exempt from payment. (Gittin 5:4, Rambam Mazik 7:1-4, Shulchan Arukh CM 385:1)

Comment: "unnoticeable" sounds like the damage won't be noticed because it's too slight but that someone looking carefully or looking for it will see it. IIUC that's not the intent here. That said, I can't think of a better one-word way to say it in English.

Comment: @msh hmmm... maybe "undetectable"? "Non-physical"?

Comment: "undetectable", probably