# Can shliach sue for reimbursement when he becomes liable for me'ilah?

Tags: shlichus-agency, tractate-chagiga, meila

When *gizbar* (temple treasurer) sends a *shliach* (agent) with *hekdesh* (consecrated) money (to buy something mundane) and then recalls that the money is *hekdesh* (and thus cannot be used for mundane private purchases), the *shliach* who performs the *shlichut* (assigned task) perfectly becomes liable for *me'ila* (guilt offering for misappropriation of consecrated funds).

The gemarah [Chagiga 11a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.11a.4?lang=bi&lang2=en):

> did the agent know that there was a possibility that the money was consecrated?

essentially says that the *shliach* is an *ones* (a victim of circumstances beyond his control - normally, such people are absolved of all responsibility).

Can the *shliach* sue the *gizbar* for reimbursement for his *me'ila* expenses?

(cf. [Could a Kohen become liable for disqualifying a sacrifice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99162/2068), [Who pays for replacement korban?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91794/2068) - the same logic suggests that the answer is ***no*** because the *gizbar* did not cause the *shliach* to incur *me'ila* **intentionally**).